# why am I not being able to connect to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have newly installed Wamp Server and I am trying to develop a local site. The database which I am trying to access is Shopping. However I am getting an error while trying to access it. Can anyone please help? Please tell me what is not well written here? 
PS: I am new to PHP and Wamp Server environment. Thanks!

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "gold", "shopping") or die
("Please, check the server connection.");
$email_address = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
$completename = $_POST['complete_name'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$phone_no = $_POST['phone_no'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (email_address, password, complete_name,
address_line1, address_line2, city, state, zipcode, country, cellphone_no)
VALUES ('$email_address',(PASSWORD('$password')), '$completename', '$address1',
'$address2','$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$country', '$phone_no')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
if ($result)
{
?>
<p>
Dear, <?php echo $completename; ?> your account is successfully created
<?php
}
else
{
echo "Some error occurred. Please use different email address";
}
?>
```

[Error: warning access denied for user'root'@'localhost'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRgHX.jpg)

Comment: `mysql_error()` should be `mysqli_error()`. You can't mix the libraries. This is possibly stopping you from getting proper error reports. Anyway you need to tell us exactly what the error says. "I'm getting an error" is no use to anyone. There are lots of possible reasons an error could occur.

Comment: Also, this is not the cause of your problem, but it's a separate issue: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: *warning access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'* means it's a permissions issue with your MySQL user, check the `mysql` database - particularly the `db` and `user` tables to see if your permissions are OK. You might also want to look at PHP's [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function for storing user passwords ... once you've corrected the other SQL injection issues.

Comment: first fix the myql_error as @ADyson saying and i tried to execute same file code, working fine on my server, check your database password and check that you have created the same database and table name.

Comment: @ADyson the error says: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\addcustomer.php on line 2. I corrected mysql_error() into mysqli_error() as you suggested but it is still not solved yet.

Comment: @ADyson the error says: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\addcustomer.php on line 2. I corrected mysql_error() into mysqli_error() as you suggested but it is still not solved yet.   CD001 , as I am testing it locally, I have set a password for root user. The permissions seems to be OK too.  iwayankit That's great! Should I create a different user than root and try connecting with it? Are you able to connect using root? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you add a password to the default `root` account? It normally gets installed without a password. If you did not try leaving the password parameter as `''` i.e. an empty string

Comment: your application should not be logging in as root in any case. You should create a separate user account specifically for the application which has only the permissions that it actually needs in order to work. Logging in as root leaves a massive, unnecessary security hole that's just asking to be attacked. Create a separate user account, note the username/password. Ensure it has permissions to what it needs. Ensure also that it is configured for access via "localhost" - each host that accesses the DB with that account needs to be specified explicitly. You can google easily for more guidance

Comment: P.S. the fix to mysql_error wasn't intended to fix this issue, just a point to note, as it will report errors with the actual query. As it stands you aren't getting that far. The answer below showing to use mysqli_connect_error to report connection issues explicitly is also potentially sensible.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes! I did add a password to the default root account. I also added another user account for accessing the database. In Privileges section, the settings are as follows: 
username  hostname  type   Privileges                 Grant 
david       localhost   global  ALL PRIVILEGES  The error still persists although I provided all privilege access to the user david. Is there something that I am not paying attention to?

Answer (score 1):

**Your database is required password so please check database credentials and check connection by using below code**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username"; // set user name
$password = "password"; // set password

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Hi Aman, Thank you for your help. I checked with the code you provided but it doesn't seem to work on my system. Maybe I am not doing something well? My database name is required a password. In Privileges, the settings are as follows: 
username  hostname  type   Privileges                 Grant 
david       localhost   global  ALL PRIVILEGES     Yes

Comment: Hi Aman, Thank you for your help. I checked with the code you provided but it doesn't seem to work on my system. Maybe I am not doing something well? My database name is required a password. In Privileges, the settings are as follows: 
username  hostname  type   Privileges                 Grant 
david       localhost   global  ALL PRIVILEGES     Yes    I am still not able to find what is the exact problem. Can you please help?